# How does QGIS legend divides its classes?

Tags: qgis, legend

When making the legend in QGIS, does anybody know how QGIS divides its classes? For example, see the legend below. What do these numbers represent? Upper/lower borders, class centers?

Can anyone help me out?

[image]

Comment: the legend is just reading your symbolization classification... I would start there.

Comment: But i just do not understand the logic... Normally discrete classification should work with ranges. What is the yellow symbol saying? Is it displaying values between 0.3 and 1? 1 and 3? 0.65 and 2...?

Comment: the label for the classification is controlled by the renderer, which is hidden in the legend for some reason. but I'm guessing you're right in your assumptions...